# Analyzing tweeter with hive, regex extract

Tags: regex, twitter, hive

I am trying to analyze what are the most popular hashtags of July. So far I am able to select tweets from July, or display the most popular tweets, but I didn't sucess in putting them together. I am thinking about creating a intermediate table with july tweets, then display the popular hashtags, but I don't know how, can you help me? What about a 2 level select (select a from select b from table) ?

```
SELECT hashtags.text, count(*) as total FROM tweets
WHERE regexp_extract(created_at, "(Tue) (Jul)*", 2) = "Jul"
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(entities.hashtags) t1 AS hashtags
GROUP BY LOWER(hashtags.text), created_at
ORDER BY total_count DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Regards, K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I did this, which is pretty much what I want, but is there any mean to achieve this differently ?

Working nested query:

```
SELECT
LOWER(hashtags.text),
COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE regexp_extract(created_at,"(Tue Jul)*",1) = "Tue Jul"
  ) tweets
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(entities.hashtags) t1 AS hashtags
GROUP BY LOWER(hashtags.text)
ORDER BY total_count DESC
LIMIT 15
```

EDIT:

Ok, so if you want you can also do it by a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpdb (
   id BIGINT,
   created_at STRING,
   source STRING,
   favorited BOOLEAN,
   retweet_count INT,
   retweeted_status STRUCT<
      text:STRING,
      user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
   entities STRUCT<
      urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
      user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
      hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
   text STRING,
   user STRUCT<
      screen_name:STRING,
      name:STRING,
      friends_count:INT,
      followers_count:INT,
      statuses_count:INT,
      verified:BOOLEAN,
      utc_offset:INT,
      time_zone:STRING>,
   in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
```

Then you update it:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tmpdb
SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE regexp_extract(created_at,"(Tue Jul)*",1) = "Tue Jul"
```

And the request become as simple as this:

```
SELECT
LOWER(hashtags.text),
COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM tmpdb
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(entities.hashtags) t1 AS hashtags
GROUP BY LOWER(hashtags.text)
ORDER BY total_count DESC
LIMIT 15
```

The pro/cons about the second method:
You need to update the table if you want accurate requests, so it is not suited for one-shot request, but if you need to do multiple requests on the current state of the database, then this method is better.
Don't forget that, copying a database is a costly operation ! So know when to use it :)